# Pass array in directive attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass array in the directive attribute. It doesn't work. I tried to pass an array in the attribute of a directive and nothing happened.

```js
class Directive {
  constructor () {
    'ngInject';

    let directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="btn-group">
                   <label class="btn btn-primary classButton" 
                          ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'First'" 
                          config="{{config[0]}}">{{config[0]}}
                   </label>
                 </div>',

      controller: Controller,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {
        config: '='
      }
    };

    return directive;
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
  }
}
```

```html
<directive config="First, Second"></directive>
```

**How should I pass the array to the directive?**

Comment: try `[First, Second]`. You don't pass in an array, but invalid notations. Put [] around them to convert it to an array

Comment: You should store array in the `$scope` or `vm` and pass it as by reference because you're using two-way binding. If you just pass it in the attribute it might cause issues.

Comment: remove the `{{` and `}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maksim,

You need to pass a scope variable instead of a array constant here,

That is, declare a scope variable and assign this value to that variable like this,

```
$scope.myArray = ['Firs', 'Second'];
```

and now you can pass this scope variable to your directive.

```
<directive config="myArray"></directive>
```

It should work !!!